# Embedding an image from a linked URL in the editor does not show the image

Tags: bug, editor, images

I was trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61216608/1415724) where the image that the OP tried to use to show something, does not show up in both the preview and after being inserted in their post.

They made an edit to the question while I was typing this up, so this pertains to what was done/posted before the edit; please see [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61216608/revisions).

Side note: [This is the revision in question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61216608/3) I am talking about.

All that was showing was:

> [![Table definition][1]][1]
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ8em.jpg

instead of the image itself.

I thought that they might not have done this properly, but that wasn't the case. Because when I tried using their image link to re-insert, it failed.

I ended up not saving the edit since the OP was editing at the same time as I was trying to fix their question.

---

**Edit:**

I revisited the question and tried again, and this time it worked. Thing is, I don't know why. I saw the preview but I didn't save the edit.

Comment: It looks like it was in a code block, the code fences have to be on their own line IIRC (or at least at the start of the line or something), so the code block isn't closed

Comment: @Nick I think you may be right. I revisited the question and tried again, and this time it worked. I don't know why.

Comment: Who knows, personally this is why I prefer the 4 space indent for code, it makes it clear where it starts and stops

Comment: @Nick I agree with you on that one.

Comment: That image doesn't belong if the reason it's there is the text content ie the table--don't put that inline, tell the poster to cut & paste text.